# Sequence of Sheaves is Exact if and only if Im$\theta$= ker$\phi$ as subsheaves of $\mathscr{G}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am self-studying little bit of algebraic geometry and I got stuck in a proof I cannot understand. First of all, we define a sequence of sheaves $\mathscr F \stackrel{\theta}{\to} \mathscr{G}\stackrel{\phi}{\to}\mathscr{G}$ to be exact if the corresponding sequence on stalks is exact. According to a Proposition, a sequence of sheaves is exact if and only if Im$\theta$= Ker$\phi$ as subsheaves of $\mathscr G$.

First of all, the image presheaf is a sub-presheaf of $\mathscr G$ but why is Im$\phi$ a subsheaf of $\mathscr G$? And secondly, how can I prove the proposition above? Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your first question is the universal property of sheafification, as stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122815/universal-property-of-sheafification). The image sheaf is the sheafification of the image presheaf, so the universal property gives a map $\operatorname{img}(\phi) \to \mathscr{G}$.

Comment: If $\mathrm{Im}\phi=\mathrm{Ker}\phi$, then $(\mathrm{Im}\phi)_x=(\mathrm{Ker}\phi)_x$, therefore $\mathrm{Im}\phi_x=\mathrm{Ker}\phi_x$. Conversely, a subsheaf of a sheaf is completely determined by its stalks.

Comment: Yeah but don't I have to prove that Im$\theta\subseteq$ Ker $\phi$ first?